# Check if a user belongs to multiple groups

Tags: mysql

Having these 3 tables:

**users**

- user_id
- first_name
- etc.

**groups**

- group_id
- name
- etc.

**groups_users**

- group_id
- user_id

it's easy to check if a user belongs or not to a given group, but is it possible to check (in a single query) if a user belongs to multiple groups?

E.g. Whether user with id `1` belongs to groups `1, 2, 3, 4`?

**UPDATE**

To be more concrete I want to check if user belongs to all of the given groups, not if he belongs to one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT group_id FROM groups_users WHERE user_id=1
```

gives you all groups the user `1` belongs to.

If you have multiple groups you want to check, you can do:

```
SELECT group_id FROM groups_users WHERE user_id=1 AND group_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

if it returns no records, the user is not in group `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`.

Use `COUNT(group_id)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT group_id)` to find out how many groups the user belongs to. If it equals the number of requested groups, it belongs to all:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT group_id)=4 FROM groups_users WHERE user_id=1 AND group_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

this will return `1` if user belongs to all groups, `0` otherwise.

Comment: Very smart solution! Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Just as I had proposed!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean to ask "whether user 1 belongs to all the groups 1, 2, 3, and 4", the answer would be:

```
select case when (select count(distinct group_id)
                    from group_users
                   where user_id = 1
                     and group_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
                 ) = 4 then 'member in all four groups'
             else 'not member in all four groups'
        end
```

You can simplify the count to `count(*)`if you are sure there are no duplicate group entries for the user.